# Create a docker container using my angular app

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

Need help with create a docker container in my angular app.

Nginx configuration : app.conf

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.html index.htm;

server {
  listen 80;
  rewrite /faculty /;
  location / {
    gzip_static on;
    proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
  }
  location = /pipes/parsedate.pipe.js {
    try_files $uri /pipes/parseDate.pipe.js;
  }
  location = /services/Auth.js {
    try_files $uri /services/auth.js;
  }
  if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != "https" ) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
  }
  error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
}
```

Docker conf

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY nginx_conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY dist/a8 /usr/share/nginx/html
VOLUME /var/log/nginx
```

Commands used to run the container

```
docker build -t a82 -f docker_conf/Dockerfile .
docker run -d -p 80:80 a82
```

But i dont see anything when i run `http://localhost`.

Please help , not sure whats the issue

Comment: You should do some network checks and post them here.

For example, use netstat to look the listening ports on your machine. Maybe, the firewall is blocking all incoming connections. Maybe, it's a redirection problem...

Tell us more about it after all your checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question your directory structure should look like this:

- dist

  - a8

    - index.html (and other contents)
- docker_conf

  - Dockerfile
- nginx_conf

  - default.conf

The problem is your redirect to use HTTPS. Comment out those lines in your default.conf like this

```
#if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != "https" ) {
#  return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
#}
```

Then you can reach your `index.html` with `http://localhost`. One thing I ran into was that Chrome redirected `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`.. But `http://localhost/index.html` works. In Edge it works as expected just using `http://localhost`.

In all cases you can check the correct configuration with `curl http://localhost`.

If you want to use TLS encryption you have to provide a certificate to the server. For this see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html. Then you would have to open the 443 port as well `[...] -p 80:80 -p 443:443 [...]`.

Comment: Thank you so much @steven.westside